# How to scale video to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background video

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I want to create a background video using `HTML5` so it will scale as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background video, something similarly to the `background-size: cover;`, but to the video.

I want it to be as cross-platform/browser as possible.

**EDIT**

I meant `background-size: cover;`

Sorry for that :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this using the transform property. It adjusts the video at the center of the screen and the width properties fill the screen with the entire video.

```
video { 
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 z-index: -100;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting, and I think this is actually fit of how the `background-size: cover;` works.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using

```
background-size: 100vw 100vh;
```

> vw- view width of the screen
>   
>   vh-view height of the screen

[read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length)

Comment: Damn... I meant `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the width and height  properties and set it to 100% or use vh and vw units if the percentage does not work for you

Comment: Damn... I meant `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this, which behave similar to `background-size: cover`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container video {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <video autoplay>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">
  </video>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you, but I meant `background-size: cover;`. Sorry for that

Comment: @laudbob Updated

Comment: But this isn't scale, as `background:size: cover;` does. check here: https://jsfiddle.net/r34639bh/

Comment: @laudbob Yes it does, take a look again

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
video{
  object-fit:cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks you, but I meant `background-size: cover;`. Sorry for that

Comment: And btw, the `object-fit` isn't cross-browser.

Comment: @laudbob : I just checked on mozilla, safari and chrome. It works fine for me. Although, I am not sure about IE.